# Individual datasource for each Realm in keycloak

Tags: database, keycloak, multi-tenant, keycloak-services

I have multiple realms in my Keycloak server. I need to connect each realm to their own individual data sources .Is it possible in Keycloak?
For example:- If I have 3 realms say that realm1,realm2 and realm3 in my single Keycloak and 3 database servers db1,db2 and db3
I need to store data related to realm1 in db1 and realm2 in db2 and like that
Is it possible to connect to different databases from a single keycloak?

Comment: The question is tagged with Realm with is a relational database and part of MongoDB Realm and likely not related to this question. Please update your tags and/or clarify the question.

Comment: @Abhi Have you found any solution to this problem ? I couldn't find myself anything and have the same requirements.

Comment: Hello, you might take a look at the following extension: https://github.com/opensingular/singular-keycloak-database-federation/blob/main/screen.png you can configure DB connection info per realm